# Telegram Bot 'sendMessage' method isn't sending some strings

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I'm having a problem that I don't actually know how to fix. I'm playing with telegram's bot API using webhooks with a PHP server I installed in my VPS. I have this code (so, when someone chats to the bot, it sends the `$reply` string):

```
$reply = 'Marco Fu 0 - 0 Michael Holt';

// send reply
if(!empty($text)){
    $sendMessage =API_URL."sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=".$reply;//."&parse_mode=Markdown&disable_web_page_preview=true";
    file_get_contents($sendMessage);
}
```

But, I don't know why, when I send that particular String, and I chat to the bot, it does not reply me back. (it shoulds reply me back with that string)

But, if I change the string to `marco fu 0 - 0 michael holt` (all letters in lowercase), the bot replies back that string! It's like en enconding problem or something like that, but I cannot detect the exact problem.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it is because you didn't encode the query string. Try this:

```
$sendMessage =API_URL."sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=".urlencode($reply);
```

Comment: Awesome, it seems like this fixed the problem.

Thank you very much, Nick!

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck.